# Reset animation state during user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uikit

I have a circle that users can touch, when you touch it it changes size then reverts back to its original size to indicate you touched it.  I want users to be able to touch it as often as they like regardless of whether its currently animating or not.  I updated my animation to use the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` flag which does allow me to touch it during the animation but it doesnt behave as I'd expect.

I think I need to somehow stop the currently playing animation, reset the size to normal and then play it again, is this correct and if so how do I do it? If not what do I do?

```
- (void)pop{
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction // reverse back to original value
                 animations:^{
                     // scale down 20%
                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                 }];
}
```

Comment: Wont that make the animation look smooth but it wont look like the user pressed it twice (because it carries on from current state rather than resetting to original state?)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 30)];
[self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (IBAction)tapDown:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         // scale down 20%
                         self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
                     } completion:nil];
}


- (IBAction)tapUp:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction // reverse back to original value
                     animations:^{
                         // scale up to 100%
                         self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I just stumbled onto this, it doesnt seem to give the effect I want.  It kinda just looked like nothing happens on the second touch - I updated my code

Comment: I just edit the answer. I used button for my example. I hope this is little closer to effect you want to achieve

Comment: From a UX-pov I'd say this is a better solution. The button will seem to be pressed down until the user releases his finger and it springs back up...

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is not what you want? When the player taps and pop is called the animation should start over?

```
- (void)pop{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1); // If you want the animation to start over you need to reset the size before staring it again
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                  delay:0.0
                options: options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse  | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut| UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction // reverse back to original value
             animations:^{
                 // scale down 20%
                 self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
             }];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I put once someone mentioned removing all animations but it didnt work!